# How EfficientNet width scaling affect the FLOPS of the model?

Tags: deep-learning, efficientnet

I'm re-building the EfficientNet by [Tan et al. (2019)](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/tan19a.html). And there's something I don't understand in the width scaling factor. In the paper they tried to maximize the model accuracy for given resource constraints as:
[image]

Based on the above equation, the FLOPS exceeds by this should be d.w.r^2.
Nonetheless, in the next section:

[image]
So the FLOPS increase by (α.β^2.γ^2)^φ which is equal to d.w^2.r^2
I'm I getting this right?

Answer (score 0):

A convolution operation is worth V(input) x V(filter) FLOPs. So with an image of shape (Hx, Wx, Cx) and ith filter of shape (Hf(i), Wf(i)). If all the filters increased in width by w then with i == 1, the FLOPs exceed by w. But then the input in the followed filters also increased by w. Eg. X(1) = (Hx, Wx, Cx.w). So from i == 2 to the end of the convolutions, the FLOPs actually increase by w for the input channels and w for filter channels, which lead to the w^2 in the equation.